# React 18 create-react-app using Typescript: why does npm-start ignore my .env.development file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have a React 18 application using create-react-app. I'm using Visual Studio code for my ide. I have two .env files in my root folder (not in my scr folder). Both of them hold the same environment variable.

In my .env file I have the variable's value set to false:

```
REACT_APP_IS_CONSOLELOG=false
```

In my .env.development file I have the variable's value set to true:

```
REACT_APP_IS_CONSOLELOG=true
```

I then launch the application in Visual Studio code in a new terminal using npm-start. In my *.tsx file I output the following to the console:

```
    console.log(process.env);
    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_IS_CONSOLELOG);
```

For the first statement I see this:

{NODE_ENV: 'development', PUBLIC_URL: '', WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}

For the second statement I see "false." I am expecting to see "true" for the second statement. React is reading the environment variable from my ".env" file, instead of from my ".env.development" file. What am I doing wrong? When I run the application on my local host I want React to use environment variables from my .env.development file, not from my .env file.

According to the React documentation at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env, my setup should work.

Following a link in the documentation, I saw an instruction to install "dotenv", which I did, but it still does not work.

This is what my package.jason dependencies looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.64",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "jest-editor-support": "^30.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

This is what my package.json scripts looks like; in the "start" setting I'm loading a local ssl cert, and then calling "react-scripts start".

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Certificates/cert.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Certificates/cert.key&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add “.env.development” to the “react-scripts start” command in the “scripts” setting in package.json.

The  “scripts” setting should look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Certificates/cert.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Certificates/cert.key&&react-scripts start .env.development",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Remove “dotenv” from the dependencies setting, it is redundant.